# Open Subgroups of Affine algebraic groups

Tags: algebraic-groups

I saw this in a paper that I've been reading and I've been trying to figure out if this is true or not.

Let $G(F)$ be a affine, simple, connected, adjoint, algebraic group over a local field endowed with the topology induced by the local field.  Suppose that $H$ is a Zariski-dense subgroup of $G(F)$ that is open with respect to this topology.  Is $H$ necessarily finite index in $G$?

Can someone provide a hint?

Edit: The local field is non-archimedean.

Comment: You say it's connected - then $H$ should be the same as $G$, since the union of all other cosets of $H$ form an open set disjoint from $H$.

Comment: $G$ is Zariski-connected, but it's definitely not connected with the topology induced by the absolute value on $F$.

Comment: Hint: Take the most obvious example of $G$ and $F$ you can think of, and then think what $H$ might be.

Comment: The simplest example I can think of is $G = PSL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ with $H = PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.  This seems like $H$ is not finite index in $G$, but my intuition with these groups is shaky at best.

Comment: Now I feel foolish, of course $H$ must be infinite index in $G$.  Looking at a matrix realization for $PSL_2(\mathbb{Q}_p)$, the element $\mathrm{diag}(p^2,1,p^{-2})$ is an element of infinite order such that no power is in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z}_p)$.  Hence, the index cannot be finite.  This is unfortunate because it means there's a big hole in this paper.  Thank you for all your help!